# AngularJS $http.post method passing null arguments to JAX-RS API

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to pass some arguments with AngularJS post method:

```
function Create(email, password, phoneNumber) {
        return $http.post('resources/users/register', {email: email, password: password, phoneNumber: phoneNumber}).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    }
```

to my JAX-RS method :

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path("/register")
public Response register(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password,
                         @FormParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber) {
```

I have loggers before $http.post and on the very beggining of register method, when arguments on the web side contains info, then every argument on server is null -> I was trying to use curl method - everything was fine!

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: cURL sends application/x-www-form-urlecoded data be default. That it the kind of data you are expecting in your resource method with @FormParam. Angular sends JSON data by default. You need to make them match. If you want to use form data, then set up Angular to use form data. Otherwise set up your resource method to accept JSON

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the json object like this  :

```
{'email': email, 'password': password, 'phoneNumber': phoneNumber}
```

**Javascript var ---> String name values**

> JSON data is written as name/value pairs. A name/value pair consists
>   of a **field name (in double quotes)**, followed by a colon, followed by a
>   value:

Comment: Well, in firebug I'm trying to look at constructed JSON and it looks like that {"email": "email", "password": "password", "phoneNumber": "phoneNumber"}, but I tried to construct JSON with Yours advices - it doesn't help - I  get exactly same response.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that is your case:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/register")
```

You're missing `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help in my case